# What is the distinction between verbs like "to regard/concern" and prepositions like "regarding", "concerning", "about"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, semantics

"regard",  "concern", "refer" are stative verbs that express the state of being related or connected to something.

Why is it that words like "regarding" and "concerning" are not considered verbs but prepositions. Are these prepositions essentially just irregular verb forms?

Comment: No, they're quite regular - the _-ing_ verb suffix is the only regular inflection in English. English words can be used as any part of speech, including prepositions, **if** they have the right meaning and appear in the right constructions. So don't believe what dictionaries tell you about parts of speech. They aren't "considered" one thing or another; it's just a web designer's opinion, probly copied from an old dictionary.

Comment: @John Lawler, thanks for your response! In this case, would you consider "using" to be a preposition in some instances?- e.g.:  Dave was writing (using/with) a pencil.

Comment: If you want to call it a preposition, nobody will put you in jail. But you'd have to explain that, yes, it was really a participle, but it was being **used** as a preposition. Go right ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a section from [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) that directly addresses your question.

(Note that CGEL spends some time defending the claim that traditional grammar is wrong in treating the gerunds and the present participle as different verb forms, and says that instead we should speak of **gerund-participles,** but let's not dwell on that.)

> **2.3 Prepositions vs verbs**
>
> For the most part, verbs are clearly distinguishable from prepositions
> by their ability to occur as head of a main clause and to inflect for
> tense. There are, however, a number of prepositions that have arisen
> through the conversion of secondary, non-tensed, forms of verbs:
>
> [21]  i  *[**Barring** accidents,] they should be
> back today.*
>         ii  *There
> are five of them [ **counting/including** the driver].*
>        iii  [***Pertaining**
> to the contract negotiations,] there is nothing to report.*
>        iv  *[**Given**
> his age,] a shorter prison sentence is appropriate.*
>
> The basis for analysing the underlined words here as prepositions is
> that there is no understood subject. This is effectively the same
> criterion as we have used in distinguishing prepositions from
> adjectives: prepositions can be used in adjunct function without a
> predicand, i.e. an element of which they are understood to be
> predicated. The preposition *counting* in [ii], for example, is to be
> distinguished from the gerund-participial verb-form in:
>
> [22]  *[**Counting** his money before going to bed last
> night,] Max discovered that two
>
>           $100 notes
> were missing.*
>
> The boundary between the prepositional construction [21] and the
> verbal [22] is slightly blurred by the usage illustrated in:
>
> [23]  i  *[**Turning** now to sales,] there are
> very optimistic signs.*
>          ii  *[**Bearing**
> in mind the competitive environment,] this is a creditable
> result.*
>         iii  *[**Having**
> said that,] it must be admitted that the new plan also has
> advantages.*
>
> These differ from [22] in that no subject for the underlined verb is
> recoverable from the matrix clause. They are similar to what
> prescriptivists call the 'dangling participle' construction
> illustrated in examples such as <sup>*</sup>*Walking down the
> street, his hat fell off,* ungrammatical in the sense where it was he,
> not his hat, that was walking down the street. Unlike the latter,
> however, the examples in [23] are generally regarded as acceptable.
> They differ from the prepositional construction in that there is still
> an understood subject roughly recoverable from the context as the
> speaker or the speaker and addressees together. Syntactically, they
> differ from the prepositions with respect to the dependents permitted:
> the verbs in [23i—ii], for example, accept the same dependents as in
> tensed constructions. In [i] we have the adjunct *now* as well as the
> complement *to sales,* and we could add other adjuncts such as
> *briefly* or *if I may.* Similarly, in [ii] the PP complement *in mind* is part of the idiom *bear in mind,* and again we could add
> adjuncts (e.g. *bearing in mind, as we must, the competitive
> environment*). In [iii] *having* is a form of the perfect auxiliary,
> and - unlike any preposition - takes an obligatory past-participial
> complement; little expansion is possible this time, but that is
> because *having said* that is a more or less fixed phrase in this use.
>
> The main prepositions that are homonymous with the gerund-participle
> or past participle forms of verbs are as follows:
>
> [24]  *according* †
> **T**       *allowing* **F**           *barring*
> †      
> *concerning*       *counting*
>            *excepting*
>               *excluding*             *failing*
> †         *following*          *including*
>           *owing*
> †
> **T**              *pertaining*
> **T**       *regarding*      *respecting*
>          *saving*
> †
>           *touching*
> †            *wanting*
> †             *given*              *gone*
> † BrE        *granted*
>
> The symbol '†' indicates that the preposition differs in
> complementation and/or meaning from current usage of the verb: we have
> prepositional *according to Kim* but not verbal <sup>*</sup>*They
> accorded to Kim,* and so on. *Gone* differs from *given* and *granted*
> in that the corresponding verb is not understood passively; it is
> used, in informal style, with expressions of time or age as
> complement: *We stayed until gone midnight* ("after"); *He's gone 60*
> ("over").
>
> As prepositions, the items in [24] take an obligatory complement - an
> NP, except for those marked **T** or **F**, which take a *to* or *for*
> phrase respectively. The prepositions *during ,notwithstanding,* and
> *pending* contain the *•ing* suffix, but are not homonymous with a verb.
>
> There are also a few deverbal prepositions that take content clause
> complements: *given, granted, provided, providing, seeing* (see Ch.
> 11, §4.8).

Now let's consider these sentences you asked about:

[1]  a.  *Dave was writing **with a pencil.***
       b.  *Dave was writing **using a pencil.***

In both [1a] and [1b], the phrase in boldface functions a **means and instrument adjunct.** But that function is realized by phrases of different kinds in the two sentences.

In [1a], this function is realized by the preposition phrase (PP) *with a pencil.*  Here the preposition *with* is the [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) of the PP  (CGEL, pp. 673-675).

In [1b], this same function is realized by a [non-finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_clause) **gerund-participial clause.**

There is nothing unusual in one and the same function being realized by phrases of different kinds. Take the function of **predicative complement** (PC). A PC can just easily be an adjective phrase (*He is **very handsome***) or a noun phrase (*He is **a doctor***). When it comes to adjuncts of manner and instrument, they are most frequently realized by PPs, but they can also be realized by certain other types of phrases.

The reason why *using* is a verb in [1b] is just the one given in the section from CGEL reproduced above: there is an understood subject, namely *Dave*.

Comment: In the [original Latin version of the Parts of Speech (_Partes Orationis_ in Latin)](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/don.html), Participles were not considered Verbs, but rather  their own, different POS. There were still only 8 POS, though, because the Romans thought adjectives were just Nouns without an inherent gender.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm still a little confused- take the following:                    (1) "The student created art using/with a pencil"

(2) "Art was created using/with a pencil"

for the second sentence  the subject,  "the student", has been removed and yet "using" still makes sense. "With" is used idiomatically  and is semantically identical to "using" in these contexts.

Comment: @Ganon First, note that your sentences (1) and (2) are very closely related. We say that (1) is in a ***canonical*** form. In contrast, (2) is in a ***non-canonical*** form, because it is in the passive. (If it was interrogative, *Did the student create art using/with a pencil*, it would also be in a non-canonical form.) Now, it is a rather standard thing in grammatical analysis that matters are much clearer when considering the canonical form. The standard assumption is that the analysis of the canonical sentence mostly carries over to the analysis of its non-canonical counterparts.